# Extract a value from the output and then use it in next task

Tags: ansible

I'd like to extract just a one value from below output and to be exactly, the **host** line.

Like:

```
host: host-1.example.com
```

The playbook itself:

```yaml
---
- name: Get fortios_configuration_fact
  hosts: fortigate
  connection: httpapi
  collections:
    - fortinet.fortios
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ansible_httpapi_port: 4443
    ansible_httpapi_use_ssl: yes
    ansible_httpapi_validate_certs: no
    username: some-name

  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve Facts of FortiOS Configurable Objects
      fortinet.fortios.fortios_configuration_fact:
        access_token: "{{ vault_access_token }}"
        selector: "vpn.ssl.web_user-bookmark"
        formatters:
          - bookmarks
        params:
          name: "{{ username }}"
        sorters:
          - logon-user
      register: ssl_vpn_results

    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ ssl_vpn_results.meta.results }}"
```

And I have this Ansible output:

```yaml
  - bookmarks:
    - additional-params: ''
      apptype: vnc
      color-depth: '16'
      description: 
      domain: ''
      folder: ''
      form-data: []
      host: host-1.example.com
      keyboard-layout: en-us
      load-balancing-info: ''
      logon-password: ENC XXXX
      logon-user: some-user
      name: some-name
      port: 5909
      preconnection-blob: ''
      preconnection-id: 0
      q_origin_key: some-description
      restricted-admin: disable
      security: rdp
      send-preconnection-id: disable
      sso: disable
      sso-credential: sslvpn-login
      sso-credential-sent-once: disable
      sso-password: ''
      sso-username: ''
      url: ''
    custom-lang: ''
    name: some-name
    q_origin_key: some-description
```

Without '.meta.results' in debug message I have this output:

```yaml
ok: [fortinet_vd] => 
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    meta:
      build: 234
      http_method: GET
      http_status: 200
      mkey: user-mkey
      name: user-bookmark
      path: vpn.ssl.web
      results:
      - bookmarks:
        - additional-params: ''
          apptype: vnc
          color-depth: '16'
          description: some-description
          domain: ''
          folder: ''
          form-data: []
          host: host-1.example.com
          keyboard-layout: en-us
          load-balancing-info: ''
          logon-password: ENC XXXX
          logon-user: some-user
          name: some-name
          port: 5909
          preconnection-blob: ''
          preconnection-id: 0
          q_origin_key: some-user
          restricted-admin: disable
          security: rdp
          send-preconnection-id: disable
          sso: disable
          sso-credential: sslvpn-login
          sso-credential-sent-once: disable
          sso-password: ''
          sso-username: ''
          url: ''
      revision: 9e0c1a3432bb884fdebaeaefdb0a51be
      serial: serial-nbr
      status: success
      vdom: root
      version: v7.0.2
```

I tried many ansible filters to manipulate the data, but failed.

Can you help with any ideas?

Comment: your output is not correct either you have a key name for list (-bookmarks) either you dont have the - before bookmarks, could you show your playbook and the right output

Comment: That doesn't look like output from Ansible. Can you update your question to include a playbook that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both attributes *results* and *bookmarks* are lists. You can get the first items from the lists, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ssl_vpn_results.meta.results.0.bookmarks.0.host }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: host-1.example.com
```

There might be more items both in the *results* and *bookmarks*. You can use *json_query* to select all *host*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ssl_vpn_results.meta.results|
                 json_query('[].bookmarks[].host') }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
  msg:
    - host-1.example.com
```

You can also iterate *results* and list all hosts for a particular item, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}: {{ item.bookmarks|json_query('[].host') }}"
      loop: "{{ ssl_vpn_results.meta.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=some-name) => 
  msg: 'some-name: [''host-1.example.com'']'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this task: *results* and *bookmark*s are lists

```
- name: display
  debug:
    msg: the value of host is {{ ssl_vpn_results.meta.results.0.bookmarks.0.host }}
```

and you have the result wanted!!